# Issue with opening Infopath form in Sharepoint

Tags: infopath

I have published a InfoPath form as content type and referenced it in a document library. However when i try to open the InfoPath form from the document library i get the following error message:

Requested registry access is not allowed.   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource resource) 
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable) 
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name) 
   at Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(String keyName, String valueName, Object defaultValue) 
   at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Runtime.FormServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) 
   at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Runtime.FormServer.DeterminePremiumSku() 
   at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Runtime.FormServer.get_IsPremium() 
   at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Controls.FormServerPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
   at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Controls.FormServerPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
   at ASP._layouts_formserver_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

I got this message as well. It turned out my MOSS 2007 copy had reverted to trial mode. After making the registry changes [outlined here](http://mcse-blogs.com/certification/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed-error-with-forms-server-andor-moss.html) I got the following message after refreshing the page: `The trial period for this product has expired.`

I entered the license key again in Central Administration and everything started to work again.